# Added date to Devise and now getting errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I recently added a date of birth field to my devise registration page and use validates_timeliness to check that the date it right. However, if the date is left blank I get the below error and not sure how to fix it.

```
* Date of birth translation missing: en, activerecord, errors, models, user, attributes, date_of_birth, invalid_date
* Date of birth translation missing: en, activerecord, errors, models, user, attributes, date_of_birth, invalid_date
```

controller

```
  #validates_timeliness gem is used for validates_date
  validates_date :date_of_birth, :before => lambda { 18.years.ago }, :before_message => "must be at least 18 years old"
  validates_date :date_of_birth, :after => lambda { 106.years.ago }, :before_message => "Seriously, dude. You ain't that old."
  validates_acceptance_of :terms_of_service, :accept => true
  validates_presence_of :gender_id
```

form in action if you need to see it. http://hangwith.me/account/register

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Devise is completely internationalised and wants you to define what error message the user should receive if they enter an invalid date.

To fix this, you need to define the relevant strings in your i18n config like so:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        user:
          attributes:
            date_of_birth:
              invalid_date: 'You must be over 18 to use HangWith.me (and not too old either)!'
```

Also, if you would like to allow the user to proceed without entering a date (it's not quite clear from your question), you should set `:allow_blank` on your validates_timeliness validation.